# issues while editing the custom attribute for a category in multi-language store

Tags: magento2, category-attribute, multi-language

My store is multilanguage and I created an image type attribute for my category. What happens is that when I edit this image with the "all store views" option enabled, it changes correctly in all languages ​​except one of them, which coincidentally (or not) is the default language of the store. I do not know if this is a default behavior or a Magento bug.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?